# I need an MPI Simulator

Tags: mpi, hpc

I want to know the performance of an C application using MPI on a computing cluster, but I only have one server, whose CPU are Intel Xeon E5-2692v2 with Accelerator card(XEON PHI). Is there any tools can simulate it? I know one called MPI-SIM, but, unfortunately, it's written for IBM SP2 and a little old.

Comment: What if you started a bunch of VMs running MPI? Or rent some servers on Amazon's EC2 or a similar service? (If you try the latter one, I recommend that you give [StarCluster](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/) a try. It's basically an automatic cluster manager for EC2 which configures everything and sets up MPI and SGE. I've tried it this week, and it was brilliant.)

Comment: That CPU has 12 cores. You could try launching your program with varying numbers of MPI processes and monitor the performance to predict how it will perform on a cluster.

Comment: @kraffenetti, thanks for your reminding, but I want a more accurate result. You know, it's better to calculate the cost of communications between nodes.

Comment: @Carsten, I will try it, if I can't find a simulator, thank you!

Comment: If you are building your own mpi, there may be options you can add at configure time to force certains types of communication. For example, in MPICH, you can add the option '--enable-nemesis-dbg-nolocal' to configure to disable any local node communication via shared memory and instead use the network.